# Is this normal for Succulent propagation

Tags: succulents, propagation

[image]
I'm very new to plants and propagation. I got 2 baby succulents from 1 leaf, is this normal? Not sure of  the name of the mother plant. Also they sprouted from opposite ends of the leaf, not from where it was detached from the plant.

Comment: The number of plantlets is fine (could be even more), *but the pale colour looks like a cause of concern*.

Comment: Looks like etiolation/chlorosis. More light will likely cure it. Some succulents do reproduce like that so *that's* no cause for alarm.

Comment: They sprouted that color and have grown quite a bit since then. What should I be concerned with? I used cactus mix soil. I have a light for them and only water once a week. Any help would be appreciated. Or point me in the right direction.

Comment: Sooner or later they need to make chlorophyll. It sounds like your soil is OK. The other major factor which prevents greening up, is lack of light. White asparagus is made by keeping light out: http://www.eatingwell.com/article/276254/what-is-white-asparagus/ Some succulents require a *lot* of light, and you may not be giving your sprouts enough.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is normal to have two plants from one leaf because they grow from lateral meristems. A meristem is an area that contains undifferentiated cells that divide in a continuous manner.

If the top was undamaged, you would have ended up with three new plants instead of two because we can see from the new leaves that they have three meristematic areas (one apex and two laterals).

As others pointed out in the comments, they need more light.